# Moved CakePHP from mac to windows and model isn't loading

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to move my CakePHP setup from a mac to a windows machine. I'm now running WAMP instead of MAMP on my local machine. When I try to submit a form that calls a controller function, it gives me the following error (which supposedly is called "Error 500" and is thrown for everything):

```
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

The first line in the stack trace points to this line in my VariantsController.php:

```
$this->loadModel('Variant');
```

**Here are all the debugging things I've tried:**

If I comment out that line, the stack trace points to the line in `core/cake/controller/controller.php` which calls `$this->loadModel` on `'Variant'`. No help there.

If I add the line `die(pr($this->Variant));` as the first line of my function, nothing changes.

If I replace my `home.ctp` with the `home.ctp` that originally comes with cake (and has lots of debugging info), it says everything is working and mysql is connecting to the server. However, it's not showing any colors or CSS styles. (That might just be because I am using a TwitterBootstrap plugin for CSS and it got confused. CSS is working on my normal homepage.)

My app/tmp/cache/models folder has just one empty document (I deleted two other files, but it didn't help).

Anything else I could try?

Comment: My model and controller names are uppercase everywhere, and my MYSQL table is lowercase. Would that cause a problem? Also, is it a problem that my controller is called Variants and my model is called Variant? The CakePHP manual names them Recipes and Ingredient respectively.

Comment: Check that you have the right PHP version for the version of Cake you're running.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: Put below code in model. 
CakePHP 2 => public $name = 'Customer'; CakePHP 1.2 or 1.3 => var $name = 'Customer'; Add name variable to all model.

Comment: Turning debug on (or reading the reason for the 500 in the error log) is step-0 for debugging any problem. There doesn't seem to be any useful info in the question.